# What is "n:0" as a number representation?

Tags: lua, tostring

I printed a value using `print(v)` and got `7:0`.

I can't find any reference to a representation format with a colon-zero at the end.  (or with a colon-number)

I am not looking for help to change the way a value is displayed.  I am looking for an explanation of why this value is being displayed this way.  Is it indicating that the value is not quite an integer?  Is the value of a special, high-precision type?

```
lua -v -e 'a="2" ; b=1 ; c=a*b ; print( c, type(c), tostring(c) ) ;'
Lua 5.3.5  Copyright (C) 1994-2018 Lua.org, PUC-Rio
2:0 number  2:0
```

This is QLua 5.3.5 under Android.

Lua 5.4.2 under Windows (lua-5.4.2_Win32_bin.zip, probably from SourceForge) does not do this:  It just prints "2".

Comment: Can't reproduce (Lua 5.3.4 on Windows) -- it prints `2.0     number  2.0` for me... Looks like it's printing a colon instead of dot as a decimal separator.

Comment: What is your current [locale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locale_(computer_software))? Use a program like [`locale`](https://man.openbsd.org/locale.1) from a terminal, or [`print(os.setlocale())`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-os.setlocale) from Lua.

Comment: print(os.setlocale()) --> C.UTF-8

Comment: I don't think it's trying to use a colon instead of a period as a decimal separator:  In the original program, the same column that displayed "7:0" also displayed "2.333".

Comment: `c` in your example should be the number `2.0`; we should expect `print(2.0)` to give the same result. (Hard to discriminate numbers, but e.g. `math.type(c)=="float" and c==2`) ("2" in Lua 5.4 is expected as coercion in arithmetic contexts is handled differently.) Lua doesn't specify how numbers are printed unless you do the string conversion explicitly, but a normal implementation explicitly adds "." via `localeconv()->decimal_point[0]` here. In the C locale, we expect `.` to be the decimal separator. Maybe possible it for the font to display this strangely or other weird downstream behavior.

Comment: Also possible that Lua is not adding the `.` itself if its normal decimal formatting doesn't produce something that looks like an integer, but it will normally use `sprintf` with `%.14g` here which will produce "2" and it will add the ".0" as described above. In any case, I think this seems like quite surprising behavior.

Comment: What *exactly* is *QLua*? The SO tag [tag:qlua] is sparse, and searching for this term brings up conflicting results (seeing results for ML-related topics, Android apps, Qt-bindings, etc.). I see a listing for an Android app, but the Lua version in its description does not appear to match yours.

Comment: Sorry for spam, but I want to also note that given that only ".0" floats seems affected, this would make some sense if there is something wrong with the portion of Lua that adds the ".0" explicitly for such numbers (rather than other decimal separators which are produced directly by `sprintf`.

Comment: Is [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quseit.qlua5pro2&hl=zh) the "QLua" you are referring to?

Comment: We unfortunately can hardly debug proprietary software. Is there any particular reason to use QLua rather than running a proper Lua inside [Termux](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.quseit.qlua5pro2&hl=zh)?

Comment: @Luatic I think that is the same QLua.

Comment: Aside from the fact that I want nothing to do with Termux, I think I ended up with QLua after downloading several.  QLua was the one I was able to use from the command line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question was:  What does "7:0" mean as the representation of a number whose value is at least close to 7.

The answer seems to be:  It's a quirk of QLua.

I tried [the online parser at JDoodle](https://www.jdoodle.com/execute-lua-online/):

- the 5.3 versions all produced "2.0"
- the 5.4 version produced "2"

If I pursue this, I think it will have to be with the people associated with QLua.